# what is "Runtime Implementation from ASSEMBLE NAME" in visual studio 2010 Setup Project? (Installer Extension Setup Project in vs 2015)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, windows-installer, setup-deployment

When adding an output to a target directory there are several types of outputs per project you can choose from. Most of them are pretty self descriptive, but i don't understand the meaning of "Runtime Implementation" and i have'nt seen it anywhere in MSDN or in other places online

Comment: You should say which Visual Studio Setup Project version you're using. I have VS 2015 and that choice appears nowhere, not even in the Project Output choices. Assuming you mean Installer Extension project and not InstallShield LE.

Comment: edited the question. thanks

Comment: just checked, that option also exists in  InstallShield LE under "Add Project Output"

Comment: I was wondering the exact same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the installed [Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9)
The "Runtime Implementation from ..." 
"Contains the runtime implementation assemblies for the targeted framework."
So if you are targetting .NET Framework 4.6.1 the setup project will bundle the assemblies allowing your project to run on that CLR.

Comment: so runtime implementation means I would get the runtime implementation. great. care to elaborate? what does it mean? what is "bundle the assemblies"? will it create one file from all of them? zip them?

Comment: "Runtime implementation" is your dotnet implementation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework - this will allow your application to run on a machine where your targetted dotnet framework is not yet installed.
"Bundle the assemblies" is the packaging of those assemblies into the MSI file.
Here is another microsoft article on the topic: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbb4k3e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks. i hope its  correct, since i'm not likely to test that anytime soon :)